# Check if one 2d lists contains all elements of another 2d list

Tags: python, list

I would like to check if one 2d lists(list of lists) contains all elements of another 2d list. Assume the lists are supposed to be identical and sorted the same way but one entry is missing from the second list. I want the program to return the index of where the missing entry should be. I know how to do this for 1d lists, but this doesn't work for 2d lists. My idea was something like this, but it doesn't work for 2d lists:

```
list1 = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[8,9]]
list2 = [[1,2],[3,4],[7,8],[8,9]]

present = True
i = 0
while present == True:
    for val in list1: #list1 is the full list
        if val in list2: #list2 is the list missing an element
            present = True
        else:
            present = False
            print("missing value")
            print(i)
    i+=1
```

How can I make this work for 2d lists?

Comment: Sample input and the expected output are much appreciated. Always provide [mcve].

Comment: you want to check if val is not present in the second list. Once that part is figured out, you can move onto locating where exactly that element is located in the first list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try using a single run through say, list A as a nested loop, and compare A[i][j] to B[i][j] at each iteration. If at any point they are not the same, or the list length is not the same, you can conclude that they arent the same.

```
for i in A:
  for j in i:
    if A[i][j] != B[i][j]:
      break
```